# Match two pandas dataframe depending on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, match

I have two datasets (**df_persons** and **df_database**). Both of them have the same structure:

| cu_id | sex | eye_colour | favourite_sport | cash_on_account |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | m | blue | soccer | 15 |
| 2 | f | green | tennis | 25 |
| 3 | m | brown | ski | 33 |

*(much more rows with various combinations of sex, eye_colour and favourite_sport)*

**For each individuals of the rows/cu_ids in persons, I'm looking for a similar match in database.**

**There are certain rules to follow:**

Loop through every row/cu_id from persons

- 1: search in database for a row with the **same values for sex, eye_colour, favourite_sport**

  - if there is exactly one row, simply return cu_id
  - if there is more than one row, sort the results by cash_on_account and return cu_id from top row
  - if there is no matching row, proceed with 2, else to 5
- 2: search in database for a row with the **same values for sex and eye_colour** (ignore favourite_sport!)

  - if there is exactly one row, simply return cu_id
  - if there is more than one row, sort the results by cash_on_account and return cu_id from top row
  - if there is no matching row, proceed with 3, else to 5
- 3: search in database for a row with the **same values for sex only** (ignore eye_colour and favourite_sport)

  - if there is exactly one row, simply return cu_id
  - if there is more than one row, sort the results by cash_on_account and return cu_id from top row
  - if there is no matching row, simly sort by cash_on_account and return cu_id from top row
  - proceed to 5
- 5: **Everytime a cu_id in persona got a "match", this "match" is not allowed to get used another time. Proceed to next row in persons**

In other words, we are **looking (in another table) for the most similar user for persons**.
**Every user from the database can only be used once.**
The **order of comparison is important** (only if sex+eye_colour+favourite_sport are matching, it's a match - otherwise only if sex+eye_colour or even just sex. Matching sex+favourite_sport is NO valid match).

```
import pandas as pd
 
database = [['1', 'm', 'blue', 'soccer', 10], ['2', 'm', 'green', 'tennis', 15], ['3', 'f', 'brown', 'ski', 14], ['4', 'm', 'blue', 'soccer', 10], ['5', 'm', 'green', 'tennis', 15], ['6', 'f', 'brown', 'ski', 14], ['7', 'm', 'blue', 'soccer', 10], ['8', 'f', 'green', 'tennis', 15], ['9', 'm', 'brown', 'ski', 14], ['10', 'f', 'blue', 'soccer', 10], ['11', 'm', 'green', 'tennis', 15], ['12', 'm', 'brown', 'ski', 14], ['13', 'f', 'blue', 'tennis', 10], ['14', 'm', 'green', 'ski', 15], ['15', 'f', 'green', 'soccer', 14]]
persons = [['1', 'm', 'blue', 'soccer', 10], ['2', 'm', 'green', 'tennis', 15], ['3', 'f', 'brown', 'ski', 14]]
 
# Create the pandas DataFrame
database = pd.DataFrame(db, columns=['cu_id', 'sex', 'eye_colour', 'favourite_sport', 'cash_on_account'])
persons = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['cu_id', 'sex', 'eye_colour', 'favourite_sport', 'cash_on_account'])
```

I simply can't wrap my head around that problem, without using a for loop and extensive comparisons/filtering (especially because I'm just allowed to match every user from database just once).

Is there any guidance you could offer for problems like that?

Best regards,
worky

Comment: you should provide the expected output for clarity, and if you have the loop code to achieve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would merging these dataframes on your conditions in the given order and only checking non matched ones in the next merge work for you?
Like this:

```
database = [['1', 'm', 'blue', 'soccer', 10], ['2', 'm', 'green', 'tennis', 15], ['3', 'f', 'brown', 'ski', 14], ['4', 'm', 'blue', 'soccer', 10], ['5', 'm', 'green', 'tennis', 15], ['6', 'f', 'brown', 'ski', 14], ['7', 'm', 'blue', 'soccer', 10], ['8', 'f', 'green', 'tennis', 15], ['9', 'm', 'brown', 'ski', 14], ['10', 'f', 'blue', 'soccer', 10], ['11', 'm', 'green', 'tennis', 15], ['12', 'm', 'brown', 'ski', 14], ['13', 'f', 'blue', 'tennis', 10], ['14', 'm', 'green', 'ski', 15], ['15', 'f', 'green', 'soccer', 14]]
persons = [['1', 'm', 'blue', 'soccer', 10], ['2', 'm', 'green', 'tennis', 15], ['3', 'f', 'brown', 'ski', 14]]
 
# Create the pandas DataFrame
database = pd.DataFrame(database, columns=['cu_id', 'sex', 'eye_colour', 'favourite_sport', 'cash_on_account'])
persons = pd.DataFrame(persons, columns=['cu_id', 'sex', 'eye_colour', 'favourite_sport', 'cash_on_account'])

m1 = persons.merge(database, how='inner', on=['sex', 'eye_colour', 'favourite_sport']) \
    .sort_values('cash_on_account_x', ascending=False) \
    .drop_duplicates(subset='cu_id_x', keep='first') \
    .reset_index(drop=True)

persons2 = persons[~persons['cu_id'].isin(m1.cu_id_x.unique())]

m2 = persons2.merge(database, how='inner', on=['sex', 'eye_colour']) \
    .sort_values('cash_on_account_x', ascending=False) \
    .drop_duplicates(subset='cu_id_x', keep='first') \
    .reset_index(drop=True)

persons3 = persons2[~persons2['cu_id'].isin(m2.cu_id_x.unique())]

m3 = persons3.merge(database, how='inner', on=['sex']) \
    .sort_values('cash_on_account_x', ascending=False) \
    .drop_duplicates(subset='cu_id_x', keep='first') \
    .reset_index(drop=True)

m1['match_type'] = 'match_type_one'
m2['match_type'] = 'match_type_two'
m3['match_type'] = 'match_type_three'

cols = ['cu_id_x', 'match_type']

final_df = pd.concat([m1[cols], m2[cols], m3[cols]])
```

Comment: Oh, that's a great solution! Easy to read and understand - and fast! I only had to change a few things, and it now works like a charm. Thank you so much! (edit: I added new code in original post)

Comment: You are very welcome, I am glad it solved your problem!